# How to combine two counts using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Using Laravel 8 for a restful API.
A table in the database has following fields

> report_date , supervisor_id and supervisor_note

I want to retrieve a result that counts the number of reports on any given day date and also counts all of the `null` values in `supervisor_notes` field.

I am using the following Laravel code:

```
$reports=DB::table('reports')
        ->where('supervisor_id','like', '%'.$supervisor_id.'%')
        ->select('report_date', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->groupBy('report_date')
        ->get();
```

I don't know how to combine the code with the second count condition in the same query

Comment: You are not using Eloquent, you are using query builder. Eloquent would look like `Supervisor::find($supervisor_id)->reports()->select('report_date', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->groupBy('report_date')->get();`

Comment: sorry i update the question 
i don't have a model called Supervisor i have Report model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation here

```
$reports=DB::table('reports')
        ->where('supervisor_id','=', $supervisor_id)
        ->select([
            'report_date',
            DB::raw('count(*) as total'),
            DB::raw('sum(case when supervisor_note is null or supervisor_note = "" then 1 else 0 end) as notes_total')
        ])
        ->groupBy('report_date')
        ->get();
```

Also if `supervisor_id` is integer column and `$supervisor_id` also holds integer value then use exact integer matching like `=` instead of using string comparison using `like` clause